# What is a correct way to update a property using Cypher?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb, opencypher

I have nodes that have first name. I want to update all of the names John to Johan. Is there a difference between this two queries? The end result seems the same to me.

Query 1

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.name= "John"
SET p += {name: "Johan"};
```

Query 2

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.name= "John"
SET p.name="Johan";
```

I've run the `PROFILE` for both queries, and they are rather similar.

```
PROFILE MATCH (p:Person) WHERE p.name= "John" SET p += {name: "Johan"};
```

[image]

```
PROFILE MATCH (p:Person) WHERE p.name= "John" SET p.name="Johan";
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There certainly is a "difference", since Query 1 uses the `SetProperties` operation to copy *all* the properties from a map (that happens to have a single property), whereas Query 2 uses `SetProperty` to set a single property from a literal.

I think the most important reason for using the `+=` syntax occurs when there are a lot of properties to be set. In that case, it is a lot easier (and less brittle) to write:

```
SET p += x
```

than:

```
SET p.a = x.a, p.b = x.b, p.c = x.c, ...
    or
SET p.a = 123, p.b = true, p.c = 'Fred', ...
```

Especially if processing earlier in the query provides `x` for free. But even if you have to create the `x` map, the result is more readable:

```
WITH p, {a: 123, b: true, c: 'Fred', ...} AS x
SET p += x
```